# How to find the index with the same value in three arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Data shapes are:

```
(675369, 3)
(675369, 3)
(670877, 3)
```

The meaning of `axis=1` is the `xyz` coordinate value.

So want to get same `xyz` value in three arrays.

How to find the index with the same value in three arrays?

Comment: How is this defined in your code?

Comment: your question is not clear !

Comment: please give the sample input output

Answer (score -1, accepted):

***If*** all the arrays ***are of the same length*** you can just go through them until you find an index that is the same for all 3.

For example (python, O(n))

```
def findMatchingIndex(a, b, c):
    for index, val in enumerate(a): # enumerate through a to get the index of the item we are looking at...
        if val == b[index] and b[index] == c[index]: # if a = b and b = c then a = c
            return index # return the first shared index we find
    return -1 # or -1 for no index.

# for example...
findMatchingIndex([1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1]) # = 1
findMatchingIndex([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [3, 2, 1]) # = -1
```

**EDIT**

However if they are not of the same length you will want to use the lowest common denominator which would be the minimum length.

```
def findMatchingIndex2(a, b, c): 
    # get the smallest size
    size = sorted( [ len(a), len(b), len(c) ] )[0] # sort the lengths of the arrays and get the smallest/first one

    for index in range (0, size): # go until the smallest array is done
        if a[index] == b[index] and b[index] == c[index]: # if a = b and b = c then a = c
            return index # return the first shared index we find
    return -1 # or -1 for no index.

# for example...
findMatchingIndex2([1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1]) # = 1
findMatchingIndex2([1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3]) # = 2
findMatchingIndex2([1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 3], [3, 3]) # = -1
```

Comment: I agree, if they are not the same size this algorithm will fail. I understood the question to be how to find a matching index in an XYZ grid where all 3 arrays have equal length (since they are matching pairs)

Comment: @chrisz I created another version that supports arrays of various sizes